# jQuery select elements same class and append corresponding values from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to programming so not sure if this could be done in jQuery.

I need to select a group of paragraphs with the same class, and then assign them a value from an array (replacing their content or appending it to the paragraph)  so for the first item the index 0 from the array for second paragraph index 1 of the array and so on.

I'm guessing i'll have to do a loop an each() kind of function so this is what I came up with

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    writeValues('values','.mainPageMeters');
});

function writeValues ( a , b ) {
    var mCount = 0;
    var mValues = $('<p>');

    $("p.mainPageMeters" + a).each(function() {
        $(this).html('<p>' + mCount + '</p>' +    $(this).html());
        mValues.append($('<p>' + mCount++ + $(this).text() + '</p>')); 
    });

    $("" + b).append(mValues);
}



<p class="mainPageMeters">Loren Ipsum bla bla bla </p>
<p class="mainPageMeters">Loren Ipsum bla bla bla </p>
<p>Loren Ipsum bla bla bla </p>
<p class="mainPageMeters">Loren Ipsum bla bla bla </p>
```

Comment: one issue is that you are using writeValues before you define it.

Comment: Where's the array you mentioned? What should the final HTML look like?

Comment: @raym0nd: No, that is not an issue. Function declaration can be everywhere in the scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, it looks like you just need a bit more practice with JS. Here's a quick example I whipped up, I think this is what you're trying to do.

```
​var arr, numOfWords, paragraphs;

​arr = ["newFoo", "newBar"]​​​;
paragraphs = $(".myClass")

    // here I'm using jQuery to loop over each paragraph
    paragraphs.each(function (i, elem) {
       // here I assign the paragraphs text to the array's current index
       $(elem).text( arr[i] );    
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n3GKf/

Comment: I am a noob in the programming whorl that includes jQuery I'm taking some online courses at codecademy and w3schools

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understand correctly what you intend to do, but maybe this helps:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    array = ["first", "second", "third"];
    $("p.your-class").each(function(i, $p) {
        $p.html(array[i]);    // or
        $p.append(array[i]);
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this code and run it in jsFiddle with the append and it's not running (I did get rid of the html line)